# Passing data between module and custom item renderer

Tags: flex4, renderer

i'm facing with this problem:
I've a module containing something like this:

```
<s:TextInput id="query" 
                       width="100%" 
                       minHeight="50"
                       change="doQuery"/>
          <s:List id = "items"
                  width="100%" 
                  height="100%"
                  minHeight="200" 
                  maxHeight="200"
                  itemRenderer = "renderer.myCustomRenderer"
                  dataProvider = "{itemList}"/>
```

my custom item renderer need to know what I'm writing into 'query' TextInput.
Is there a way to pass query.text string to my renderer?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign itemRenderer property at runtime when query TextInput changes :

```
var myRenderer:myCustomRenderer = new ClassFactory(myCustomRenderer);
sparkRenderer.properties = { query: query.text };
items.itemRenderer = sparkRenderer
```

Comment: Thank you so much! In the mean time i've resolved adding a function on module interface: getQueryString() that get me query.text and call it from itemRenderer in this way: var string:String=((this.parentApplication as moduleLoaderTester).getQueryString()).  But your way is really more elegant!!